# ERROR -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: command-line, bash, apache2

I got the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

while executing:

```
a2ensite <span style="color: #ff0000;">mysite.conf</span>
```

I am following this tutorial: https://subinsb.com/ubuntu-linux-create-localhost-website/

Comment: That seems like an error in the tutorial (presumably the author intended to color the `mysite.conf` argument but the raw HTML code got displayed)

Answer (score 4):

Actually you want to tell to **a**pache**2** to **en**able a **site** configuration file named **mysite.conf**:

```
a2ensite mysite.conf
```

---

The rest part of the line is HTML code that shouldn't be displayed in this way. As [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) said this is ан error in the tutorial. In result the syntax is completely wrong... This code contains the semicolon character `;` that can be used as newline token in Bash - the default user's shell in Ubuntu.

The command `a2ensite` expects name of any file located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. The name must end with `.conf`. The command creates symbolic links for these files into the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`, thus they become *enabled*, when you reload the Apache's configuration.